# TypeScript - Passing in an anonymous function as method parameter

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have implemented a List like class and in it I have a method

`public forEach(func: (id: number, str: string) => void )`.

I can call this method (where cars and _allCars are both instances of this List class) like this for example

```
this.cars.forEach((carIndex, car) =>
          this._allCars.add(car));
```

.

My question is, how can I insert some logic into the function parameter? I would like to do something like

```
this.cars.forEach((carIndex, car) =>
          if(true)
            this._allCars.add(car));
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by wrapping the body in curly braces:

```
this.cars.forEach((carIndex, car) => {
    if(true) this._allCars.add(car);
    // more logic if you want too...
});
```